# How can we access tap recognition on the LSM6DS3 in the movesense device?

Tags: movesense

For example, I'd like to start the onboard datalogger when a user taps the device, and stop the datalogger when they double-tap.

Answer (score 0):

TAP and DOUBLE_TAP are available in the [/System/States -API](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/src/master/MovesenseCoreLib/resources/movesense-api/system/states.yaml). However simultaneous TAP & DOUBLE_TAP are not possible from the sensor, so to get both you'll have to do the following:

1. SUBSCRIBE /System/States/4   (4 == TAP)
2. When TAP event is received trigger a one_off timer (around 600-800ms is good)
3. If a second TAP is received before the timer is triggered, reset timer and forward as DOUBLE_TAP event
4. If timer expires without any TAP detections, forward as TAP event

Other things to consider are:

- Users usually want some kind of feedback that the command went thru (e.g. LED blink or mobile sound). Without it they tend to try again and again.
- It's a good idea to test the TAP sensitivity etc. with many test subjects. Each person tends to tap differently.
- If the IMU (Acc, Gyro / Magn) are subscribed as well, the TAP detection works on the sample rate of measurement subscription. DOUBLE_TAP detection is not reliable with 13 or 26 Hz sample rates.

*Full Disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*